# How would I specify Grails resources without using modules?

Tags: grails, resources, handlebars.js

I'm using the handlebars resource plugin from Grails to compile my templates into a resource bundle for my Grails app.  However, this requires me to specify the handlerbars template in its own module.  For example:

```
modules = {
application {
    dependsOn 'handlebars_runtime'
    resource url: 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js', disposition: 'head'
    resource url: 'js/less-1.3.3.min.js', disposition: 'head'
    resource url: 'js/bootstrap.min.js'
}

newCustomer {
    dependsOn 'application'
    resource url: 'templates/new_customer_page_1.handlebars', attrs: [type: 'js'], bundle: 'bundle_application'
    resource url: 'js/newCustomerPage1.js'
}
}
```

I'd really like to move the handlebars template file and the accompanying javascript into the gsp file that uses that javascript and template.  I'd still like it bundled in the bundles, but I've noticed that new modules require me to restart my server to show up.  Not to mention I expect I'll have lots of modules defined for each page making the ApplicationResources.groovy file gigantic.  If I can push these out to the gsp file the developer creates it should keep that file down to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Can you place the items you want to be in common in a module and then move just the separate templates out to the separate gsp files?

The Resources plugin doesn't provide any facility for bundling items outside modules, that is sort of what it means to be a module, that you want the items bundled together.

One could write a separate facility to use the ResourceProcessor classes in a specific way to achieve a different behavior though.

Comment: "Can you place the items you want to be in common in a module and then move just the separate templates out to the separate gsp files?" That's exactly what I'm asking.  It sounds like the answer is NO to that question though from reading the rest of your post.

Comment: I think the answer probably is no if you want to bundle items that aren't in a module. As I mentioned, you could write a separate facility to do that. Though I wonder if it would be easier to just take the handlebar code and manually bundle it into one file that you use.